# ractive.js multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, ractivejs

This is much like the common multiple checkbox question all over the web, except my list of checkboxes is dynamic.

Simplified:

```
{{#user}}
    <h2>Roles</h2>
    {{#allRoles:roleIndex}}
      <input type='checkbox' name='{{roles}}' value='{{.id}}'> {{.name}}<br>
    {{/}}
{{/}}
```

I want to iterate over allRoles (in ~/) and get an array of checked boxes in user.roles but since {{#allRoles:roleIndex}} changes the keypath, I cant figure out how to put roles inside user.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the obvious is too obvious.

name='{{user.roles}}' is what I needed